# Characteristic polynomial factor over the real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Ve=the set of symmetric 2x2 matrices

I'm trying to show that any element of Ve has a characteristic polynomial that factors over the real numbers and has two distinct eigenvalues unless the matrix is a multiple of the identity matrix.

Is there more than one way to do this? how would I go about showing this?

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 3):

Take *any* real symmetric matrix and calculate its characteristic polynomial:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{pmatrix}\implies p_A(x)=\det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-a&-b\\-b&x-c\end{vmatrix}=x^2-(a+c)x+ac-b^2$$

The above quadratic polynomial's discriminant is

$$(a+c)^2-4(ac-b^2)=(a-c)^2+4b^2$$

and this is positive unless $\;a=c\;,\;\;b=0\iff A=aI\;$ , which is a multiple of the identity matrix and for which the characteristic polynomial trivially is reducible.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that any symmetric real matrix is diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ we see that a $2\times 2$ symmetric real matrix $A$ is similar to the matrix
$$D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$$
so
$$\chi_A(x)=\chi_D(x)=(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)$$

Comment: Knowing that a real symmetric 2x2  matrix is diagonalizable is well after knowing its char. pol. is reducible, isn't it?